# Style webmedia pages on browser

Tags: javascript, css, browser, media, mp4

How to style or add js to .pdf / .jpeg / .mp4 pages ?

For example, I want to make the `width :100%` of `.page-media` [video page] but where to add the styles, I am just not getting the starting point and the end point.
For example, facebook and intagram show the images and have toolbars even on the page of extension `.jpeg` etc.

[P.S. Sorry for very confusing title, I failed to think of any suitable title :/]

Answer (score 0):

You can't serve styles in an image.

You need to serve an HTML page that contains both the image and your styles.
You can do this even from a URL that happens to end in `.jpg`; extensions don't matter at all.